# How to import an existing ubuntu into wsl

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Does anyone know how to import an existing Ubuntu system into a windows subsystem?

Ubuntu system info:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS x86_64
Host: 20H5006TGE ThinkPad E570
Kernel: 5.4.0-56-generic 
CPU: Intel i5-7200U (4) @ 3.100GHz 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 620 
Memory: 6844MiB / 15916MiB
```

Windows system info:

```
Edition: Windows 10 Pro
Version 1909
```

I want to run it on wsl2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server? Any particular version? WSL1 or WSL2? Specificity is *really* important if you’re looking for clear answers that solve problems 

Comment: @Matigo I edited the question. I hope that helps.

Comment: WSL2 is a Microsoft's product, you need to ask on Windows forums how to manage VMs. Windows 10 Pro has Hyper-V so it would make more sense to just use it.